# C# non-persistent `static` keyword?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, unique

I come from a C/C++ background and am having trouble doing some things in C#. My problem right now is that I need a `static` keyword that works like in C++. So that the property is global to all instances of the class, which is what C#'s does. But what I don't want is the persistence in C#(/ASP.NET). I want the static property global to all instances of a class on the currently executing page only.

How can it be possible to do this?

Basically what I'm using this for is unique naming which must only be unique on the currently executing page. If the static property is persistent, then there is a much higher chance of integer rollover in periods of high traffic, which could lead to the same value being used twice.

Like if someone went to a page with

```
static int i=0;
page_load...{
  lbl.Text=i;
  i++;
}
```

then they would get 0. and if someone else went to the same page they would also get 0. But also having the static property so that it's the same in all instances of the class.

Comment: The simple solution would be to use a long. A 64-bit value doesn't roll over any time soon. Honestly, I doubt a 32-bit integer would either. That'd still be 4 billion requests. I doubt your site generates that many visits during the average session duration.

Comment: probably true.. but it's never good to assume "oh we'll never have that many people" cause it could very well happen if per page request this number could be incremented like 100 or more times

Comment: You're assuming no matter what. Even if the number is per page, it can overflow if that page is requested often enough. The trick is to make sensible assumptions. No matter how often the page is requested, a 64-bit integer *will not overflow*. You could increment it every nanosecond, and it wouldn't wrap around for 584 years.

Comment: Well... if you get 1000 hits a second (read: can actually serve that many within a single appdomain!), then a signed 32-bit integer will overflow after 23 non-stop days of load.  Now, I can imagine that a 64-bit value is just the simpler route, but if you're looking for a unique ID that's valid for about the length of the average session, if you aware of the limitations, no matter what the load, you're not going to run into trouble.  And sometimes it's worth saving bits; for instance if you need to stick the value into the url.

Comment: Also, I was looking for a way to count recursions in recursive functions(across separate instances) to prevent overflow. if you use static and a page crashes you now have a recursive level 10-20 above what it should be(though the stack is actually empty) which can play havok in a production environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no really clean way to do this, but if your object will always live in the context of a HTTP page/request, you could use the [`Items` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) of the current `HttpContext`:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private static readonly string _itemKey = "Key Goes Here";
    private readonly HttpContext _context;

    public YourClass()
    {
        _context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (_context == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Boom!");

        // set a default value here if you like...
        if (_context.Items[_itemKey] == null)
        {
            _context.Items[_itemKey] = new YourType("Default Value");
        }
    }

    public YourType NonPersistentStatic
    {
        get { return (YourType)(_context.Items[_itemKey]); }
        set { _context.Items[_itemKey] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we both got this nailed down as the answer and it's just the poster's preference if he wants to exist per session or per request. I think session makes more sense since why would it need to be static only for a request since that could be handled by an instance object passed around or dependency injected.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you're not going to be able to get what you want in this case because you're trying to combine two incompatible concepts

- static is a modifier in C# which frees a member (method, property, field, etc ...) from being bound to an instance.  It's instance more accurately bound to a type within an AppDomain.
- A counter specific to the current executing page is necessarily associated with an instance

I think your best bet is to create an instance level property and do what is needed to pass down the instance and update the counter.

But I'm still a bit unclear about your scenario.  It seems like you could want any of the following ...

- A property specific to the currently instance of the executing page
- A property specific to all instances of the executing page
- A property specific to the all uses of the page within the current session

Could you clarify which of these is the problem?

Comment: I don't think he can do this with any specific keyword but I believe I provided the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I understand your question 100% however...

I believe what your really looking for is to store an object in the Session.

What I would do is something like this

```
public class PageBase : Page
{

    public MyObject Foo 
    {
        get { return (MyObject)Session["myobject"]; }
        set { Session["myobject"] = value; }
    }
}
```

And change your pages to inherit from PageBase

**Edit:** After looking up the implications on `[ThreadStatic]` inside ASP.NET I came across this blog post by Scott Hanselmen saying, no no no! [A tale of two techniques: The [ThreadStatic] Attribute and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ATaleOfTwoTechniquesTheThreadStaticAttributeAndSystemWebHttpContextCurrentItems.aspx). He also pointed out the existence of the HttpContext having a builtin dictionary that you can store objects in. I forgot entirely about this mostly because so far I've never once found anything useful for it.

Comment: `Session` persists across different requests (for the same user).

Comment: @Luke: That's true, but reading between the lines... that may be what the original poster wants.

Comment: No, it's not.. though per-user it should never overflow(for surely someone can't generate a over 10,000 page requests in an 8 hour day(assuming they are active enough to keep session from dying)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you referencing the "static" from? If it is just child controls, I would add a regular instance property to your page class, then reference that variable through the page property on the child controls.

```
public class DefaultPage : Page {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
} 

public class DefaultControl : UserControl {
    //...
    ((DefaultPage)this.Page).MyProperty
    //...
}
```

Honestly though, if I saw this code, I would think the design is a little backwards. Page should be supplying the user control with all of the data it needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a ThreadStatic variable, however that is not a good solution. It would work, but it's not a robust way to handle it. A ThreadStatic variable is for example only initialized for the first thread, so you need to handle the initialization for each thread yourself.

First of all you should look into the built in capabilities for providing a unique id for each element. If you for example have a repeater so that the same control is repeated, each iteration gets a unique id which is prepended to the control id. You can use the ClientID property to get this unique id.

If you need to handle the naming yourself, you should use a member variable in the Page class to keep track of the naming. You can easily initialize the variable in the constructor of the class, and as the variable doesn't exist before that, you are sure that you can't accidentally use it before it's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need that. You can store stuff unique to a session in the HTTPContext.Current.Session. You can store stuff that is unique to a request in HTTPContext.Current.ViewState.

To do what you want to do, you would need to declare an application scopped variable of an object that that is threadsafe.The example below example would give you a unique number across all pages.

1) Create a thread-safe counter class since the Application scopped variables are not thread safe by defaut

```
public class ThreadSafeCounter
{
  private object _padlock = new object;
  private int _counterValue = 0;

  public int GetNextValue()
  {
     int temp;
     lock(_padlock)
     {
       _counter++;
       temp = _counter;
     }
     return temp;
  }

}
```

2) Create the application variable in the Global.asax Application_Start event

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["MyCounter"] = new ThreadSafeCounter();
```

3) Access this in your page's code behind

```
var counter = HttpContext.Current.Application["MyCounter"] as ThreadSafeCounter;
if (counter != null)
{
  var uniqueValue = counter.GetNextValue();
  // DO SOME WORK HERE
}
else
{
  //throw some exception here
}
```

**A potential gotcha:**
If you deploy this across a server farm or you have more than 1 worker process, make sure that your session mode is either a state server or SQL Server based because if it is InProc the each server/process that handles the request will have its own counter.